# Use tlmgr to install only packages - no source or doc

Tags: texlive, installing, texlive-2017, tlmgr

Running texlive2017.

When installing, I chose not to install source and doc trees choosing to depend on `tlmgr install --reinstall --with-doc` option when needed.

But if I need to install a package later with `tlmgr install` how do I tell the command to install ONLY the package without the doc or source?

Comment: Not installing the sources would mean omitting the TeX files that form the package  (for most packages).

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I am not an expert. But texlive installation provides for not installing font/ macro source tree and font/ macro doc tree. Please see [this image](http://i.imgur.com/2H3cqBy.png). I had opted for both to reduce the download size. And the installation seems to work fine, except when it finds a missing package or two.

Comment: I didn't know that there is an option to drop the font or macro source tree (I find the dropping of the later not really useful, unless the interest is limited to the documentation only). I agree in case of `.dtx` files where the source file is a documented package file basically, in order to generate doc and package files.

Answer (score 2):

OK. Here is an answer. When we use `tlmgr install package` it installs only the package. If we want to install doc/ source, we need to use `--with-doc --with-source` options. HTH.

Comment: I don't understand your answer! You asked for installing a package without source and doc, but this is happening already since you have chosen the relevant setting. Your answer explains how to install a package *with* source and doc...

Comment: @norbert Yes. I agree with you. But in `tlmgr --help` I did not find an explicit mention of what happens when `--with-doc --with-source` options are not given. That led me to ask the question, in the first place. When I discovered the default behaviour by chance, I thought it would be useful if it is captured as an answer here. Also, since you have such a high reputation and are a maintainer yourself, may I ask if I can suggest a very minor change in the output of `tlmgr --help`? that will explicitly address this issue.

Comment: Sure enough, just send your corrections and improvements to the texlive mailing list or me personally, whatever you prefer. We are more than happy to improve the docs

Comment: @norbert Again, new to this, so have to ask even basic questions. To which email ID do I send this to?

Comment: texlive@tug.org or my personal, just Google my name or look into my profile ;-)